# Inherited control not showing in designerview while x86

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, inheritance, x86

I'm creating a windows app in Visual Studio 2019. I use a COM reference (IBM PCOMM v 13, 32 bit) that only works when i set project target to *x86*.

When I change target from *Any CPU* or *x64* to *x86*, the COM-reference works great. However, all the controls that I have created by inheriting, disappear from the designerview. The form is basically empty. My own controls are stored in separate .cs-files that are included in the project.

When I change target back to *Any CPU* or *x64*, my controls reappear, but the COM reference won't work (due to not *x86*).

This is the .cs code of one of the simpler controls I use in my form:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public class LabelTitle : Label
    {
        public LabelTitle()
        {
            ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 95, 165);
            Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that the standard controls work in *x86*. However, I would prefer to use my own custom controls.

How can I continue to use my own controls while building in *x86*?

Comment: What does *My own controls are stored in separate .cs-files* mean? Did you build a Library, or these Controls are part of the same Project, stored in different files? If this case, there's no reason for the Controls not to work when you change the target CPU. Unless you have errors that prevents the Designer's initialization to complete (e.g., P/Invoking with the wrong CharSet). -- Try to clean the Solution (not the Project), rebuild the Solution, close VS and restart it. Add the *alien* stuff after.

Comment: Hi Jimi. By *My own controls are stored in separate .cs-files* I mean that I right clicked on the project name in the Solution Explorer > Add > New Item. Then I chose a Visual C# Class and named it LabelTitle.cs. This .cs-file is stored in the project folder in windows (...\repos\Stackoverflow\) and hence also in the project in the Project Explorer.

I tried your suggestion to clean the solution, rebuild the solution, close VS and restart it but nothing happened.

I also tried to close VS, delete the bin and obj folders but that didn't solve it either.

Comment: Update: the forms won't reappear with Any CPU or x64 now. That's strange.

Comment: You have more / different problems there. Check the ToolBox, see if you find your Controls there. Add `[ToolboxItem(true)]` to all Custom Controls that use a nested namespace. Check the actual namespace of all your Controls, verify that it's *consistent*. -- Possibly, add all Controls to a Library that targets AnyCPU.

Comment: I tried including [ToolboxItem(true)] in the controls namespaces but it didn't work.

Comment: *in the controls namespaces*? What does that mean? That's used to decorate a class. What is the namespace of your Project and the namespace(s?) of these Controls? -- Make a test, using a clean Project. Add a couple of those Controls to a class Library (targeting AnyCPU) and reference it. Add a couple more, copying the files to the Project's directory structure and including them in the Project through Solution Explorer. Set a consistent namespace to all. Build, Design, rebuild, then add the other stuff.

Comment: I tried including [ToolboxItem(true)] in the controls namespaces but it didn't work.

However, now I get a new VS error message when I try to load a control from the toolbox. Can't upload image, so I'll write the first part of it:

*Failed to create component 'LabelTitle'. The error message follows: 'Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolServerException: Could not load file or assembly 'Stackoverflow'. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid (0x80131047) at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClient.<SendRequest...*

and then it continues for 60 rows in msg

Comment: Do as described in my previous comment and fix the namespaces of those Control. You cannot juggle namespaces as it was nothing important. -- `[ToolboxItem(true)]` is related to class definition, not the namespace.

Comment: Hi, Filledille. Can you try to unload the Com reference? And then, can you create a new Winform program to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, though I don't understand why this solves the problem.

After trying the solutions provided in the comments and reproducing the errors in new projects by adding and changing line by line, I found that it was the target framework that caused the error.

The first project (that threw errors) used the template *Windows Forms App* with **.NET 5.0** framework. However, if I instead use template *Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)* with framework **.NET 4.7.2** all my  inherited controls work perfectly fine with x86. So far, all my COM-references and my controls work great with the .NET 4.7.2 framework.